# This part of CSS wouldn't modify with Chrome Developer Tools, what to do?

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, google-chrome-devtools

Normally I edit and modify my website by first making changes in the Chrome Browser itself by using Chrome Developer Tools, however, this one won't change no matter how many times I try.
This is my website - [link](http://www.cyberfosters.com/linear-search/). There's a sidebar at the bottom right which is displayed as **block**.
I want it to display it as **inline**.
The CSS is as follows :

```
.widget-area {
float: left;
width: 200px;
}
.widget-area {
margin: 24px 0 0;
margin: 1.714285714rem 0 0;
}
```

I've just added

> display : inline;

to one of the blocks but nothing seems to change, anyone can help?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Even there are no widget at bottom left. It may be bottom right.

Comment: @AhmadSharif: Sorry! **Bottom right**, corrected.

Comment: @ZackTanner:Goal is that the sidebar should appear horizontally

Comment: @Sidsec9 You mean alongside the main post body?

Comment: @ZackTanner:No, at the bottom. I've made the width of post content to 100% so that the sidebar is shifted down. Now I want the sidebar to be horizontal instead of vertical

Comment: you could not do this with only css. you have to edit your template file.(If i make sense your goal)

Comment: Actually, I just solved it.
**.widget-area {
float : left;
display: inline-flex;
}

.widget-area aside 
{
padding: 15px;
}**